# custom message instead of technical exception message in java

Tags: java, exception

I need to manage exception like null pointer exception and in place of showing technical exception message, I need to Catch and manage these types of issues without displaying a system error/crash screen.  Display an appropriate warning or error message to the user to advise them that previously specified filter selections are invalid, and that it must be modified to fix this issue. What would be the best way to it. I used play framework to develop this app and handling exception in reporting from dynamic jasper.

Comment: don't catch NullPointerException's, fix them...

Comment: You should not catch RuntimeExceptions.

Comment: there are many caases in business apps when you have null pointers and need to catch them (maybe at a higher level). You need to set a variable/ data structure that is reused in the front end to show a good error message

Comment: A better way might be to check if(myVar == null ||myVatr.getmyProperty() == null){ myMsg = ""; } else { .... sometimes need to ahve different msgs for myVar null and myVar.getMyProperty - so multiple if checks before main logic

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
  // risky code that throw the exception
}
catch (final NullPointerException e){
  // Here you display your message
}
```

**The best being of course to check that your code doesn't have to deal with a null value.**

Comment: please don't do this, _ever_

Comment: Of course, that's definitely not the best to do. But that's what the user asked for.

Comment: Yeah, i understand that, that is why I removed the downvote, and just commented :)

Comment: Not sure teaching someone to remove null pointer exceptions by catching them is the right way, even if it is asked for. On that basis we might just tell people to put a try and catch block around the whole code and it will run on magic even when things go wrong. If his input generates null pointer exceptions he really should have better input handling and should be directed that way.

Comment: Asthor, everybody has a different way to design a program. If his way is to catch exceptions using try-catch, he may have some valid reasons (or not) to do it. However, I agree with you when you say it is not the design to adopt in 99.99% of the case. What matter is not how you catch exceptions, but more what you do when it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Test for a valid selection of filters before trying to process these filters. Then you shouldn't get `NPE`. Otherwise, you are misusing exceptions: an invalid input from a user (human) has always to be expected.